# Cannot use $count with ODataRoute Attribute

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, odata

Using the **ODataRoute** atrribute makes the **$count** not work.

```
/// Startup.cs
app.UseOData("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel());

static GetEdmModel()
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<User>("User");
    builder.EntitySet<User>("Product");
    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

```
/// MyController.cs
[EnableQuery]
[ODataRoute("User")]
public IQueryable<User> GetUser() => User.GetQuery());

[EnableQuery]
[ODataRoute("Product")]
public IQueryable<Product> GetProduct() => Product.GetQuery());
```

```
http://localhost:5901/odata/User (Works)
http://localhost:5901/odata/User/$count (Not Working)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think adding AllowedQueryOptions  to `EnableQuery`attribute might help

```cs
[EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All )]
[ODataRoute("User")]
public IQueryable<User> GetUser() => User.GetQuery());
```

Comment: Be sure to add also `count()` the routebuilder as in here:
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/first-odata-api


`app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
    {
        routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();
        routeBuilder.Expand().Select().Count().OrderBy().Filter();
    });

`

Comment: Count() is enabled, if I define one controller for each entity it works, example:

`/// UserController.cs
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<User> Get() => User.GetQuery());`

Looks like a bug, i've opened an issue: https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/issues/69